# Why does overriding negate cause static warning in Dart

Tags: dart

Having a simple class as follows is considered a static warning, why?

> operator 'negate' should return numeric type

```
 
class Vector {
      final int x,y;
      const Vector(this.x, this.y);

      Vector operator +(Vector v) { // Overrides + (a + b).
        return new Vector(x + v.x, y + v.y);
      }

      Vector operator -(Vector v) { // Overrides - (a - b).
        return new Vector(x - v.x, y - v.y);
      }

      Vector operator negate() {    // Overrides unary negation (-a).
        return new Vector(-x,-y);
      }

      String toString() => '($x,$y)';
    }

    main() {
      final v = new Vector(2,3);
      final w = new Vector(2,2);
      assert((-v).x == -2 && (-v).y == -3); // -v  == (-2,-3)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have an open bug for this: http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=3416

Answer (score 4):

As of 8/21/2012 the [Dart Specification](http://goo.gl/cj6DY) Section 7.1.2 Operators, considers defining negate with a possible nullary type as bad style and should report to the user a static warning.

> Defining a nullary method named negate or a binary method named equals
>   will have the same effect as dening an operator but is considered bad
>   style, and will cause a static warning.
>
> [...]
>
> It is a static warning if the return type of the user-declared
>   operator []= is explicitly declared and not void. It is a static
>   warning if the return type of the user-declared operator equals is
>   explicitly declared and is not bool. It is a static warning if the
>   return type of the user-declared operator negate is explicitly
>   declared and not a numerical type.

Comment: The spec doesn't look right to me. Why limit the return type of operator negate to a number? You could post it to Dart issues for asking fixes.