# Dart overriding unary minus operator

Tags: dart, dart-analyzer

As per Language specs (10.1.1 Operators) I am trying to override some operators.

I get an analyzer error when overriding the 'minus' and 'unary minus' operators - one that I don't get:

'The operator "-" is not defined on class Indentation'

but in the class I have defined it:

```
  Indentation operator -() {
    level--;
    return this;
  }
```

and I use it like `myInstance--;` and it actually does work, but still the analyzer complains and I cannot submit the code 'clean' because of the error.

I have looked up an old thread ([Why does overriding negate cause static warning in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065346/why-does-overriding-negate-cause-static-warning-in-dart)) but I think it is not relevant here.

Any advise is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--x` is the same as `x -= 1`. To use it you have to define the `operator -(p)` (not `operator -()`)

```dart
Indentation operator -(n) => new Indentation(level - n);
```